# How to linearize or formulate optimization constraints that are stated in terms of "if-then" sentence?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I am a engineer who is working on an optimization problem and my constraints are in the form of this statement "if $x_1=1$ then $d_1=1T$" where $T$ is just a given time period.

**Scenario 1**

Particularly, I need to linearize or formulate an entire system that looks like this:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_1} = 1}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_1} = 1T}
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_2} = 1}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_2} = 2T}
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_3} = 1}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_3} = 3T}
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{...}&{...}&{...}&{...}
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_n} = 1}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_n} = nT}
\end{array}
\end{array} \right.$

**Scenario 2**

$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_1} = 1}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_1} = 1T}\\
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_1} = 0}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_1} =  + \infty }
\end{array}}\\
{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_2} = 1}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_2} = 2T}\\
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_2} = 0}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_2} =  + \infty }
\end{array}}\\
{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_3} = 1}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_3} = 3T}\\
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_3} = 0}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_3} =  + \infty }
\end{array}}\\
{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{...}&{...}&{...}&{...}
\end{array}}\\
{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_n} = 1}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_n} = nT}\\
{{\rm{if}}}&{{x_n} = 0}&{{\rm{then}}}&{{d_n} =  + \infty }
\end{array}}
\end{array}} \right.$

Here, the $x$ are binary variables that satisfied ${x_1},{x_2},{x_3},...,{x_n} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}$. On the other hand, ${d_1},{d_2},{d_3},...,{d_n} \ge 0$ are just some real non-negative variables. Please help me with this.

**Editted**

For completeness, I add scenario 2 where some enforcement is needed for the system to work.

The answer of Mr @RobPratt work quite neat but are there anyway to avoid this ***Big-M formulation*** ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: Not sure what solver supports $\infty$ as the value of a variable, but for Scenario 2 you could impose $d_i=i T x_i+\infty(1-x_i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M_i$ be some constant upper bound on $d_i$. The standard linearization of $$x_i=1 \implies d_i=i T$$ is achieved by the following linear “big-M” constraints:
$$(0-i T)(1-x_i)\le d_i-i T \le (M_i-i T)(1-x_i)$$

To see that this linearization works, check the two cases. When $x_i=1$, the constraints enforce $0\le d_i-i T \le 0$, as desired.  When $x_i=0$,  the constraints enforce $0-i T\le d_i-i T \le M_i-i T$, which is redundant by the choice of $M_i$.

Comment: Thank you but this beg the question: how big should this number $M$ be ? Furthermore, will any bad thing happen if $M$ is too big or too small ?

Comment: Too large will cause numerical issues, and too small will prohibit feasible solutions that you want to allow.

Comment: So in practice I should study some statistic about the upper bound on $d_i$, and choose an avarage value for $M$ right ?

Comment: To find a good (small, data-dependent) value for $M_i$, you should consider what $d_i$ represents in your problem.

Comment: Now this is a big problem this $d_i$ is some delay that depend on $T$ but in some situation $T$ is a decision variables that also need to be optimized too. I feel so hopeless

Comment: It might be best to start a new question that describes your complete business problem and asks how to formulate it mathematically.

Comment: if I only want ${x_i} = 1 \Rightarrow {d_i} \le iT$ does that mean I have to do only this part to linearize ${d_i} - iT \le \left( {{M_i} - iT} \right)\left( {1 - {x_i}} \right)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.